# Cannot create the exe file (LNK1104 cannot open file)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, assembly, masm

I'm following the steps from [Getting Started with MASM and Visual Studio 2012](http://kipirvine.com/asm/gettingStartedVS2012/index.htm) but I keep getting the following link error:

```
LNK1104: cannot open file 'D:\...\Project_sample\Debug\ASM_Project.exe'
```

I've tried putting the project on different paths and running VS as admin, making the Debug directory writable, making sure the app is not running (this is the first compile, so it didn't even exist). I do get the object file in the Debug directory, the PDB and the log file, but not the exe.

Comment: Unguessable.  Get Hello World going first.  If you use Avast then uninstall it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The antivirus (Avira) was blocking the `.exe` file. Adding the Debug path to the list of excluded directories solved the problem.